# javascript regular expression to test e-mail

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to check the e-amil address like abc@example.co.uk or a.bc@eyample.com etc

and I am using regular expression like

```
[a-zA-Z0-9\._]+@[^.]+[a.zA-Z]+\.[a-z{2,5}]+
```

Can someone suggest how to correct it?

Thank you

Comment: It can be corrected but the best solution would be http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address

Answer (score 0):

See [Using a regular expression to validate an email address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address)

and you can try :

```
[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+-/=?\^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

Example

```
var sEmail = txtEmail;

var filter = /^([\w-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$/;

if (filter.test(sEmail)) {
    return true;
}
else {
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you make an input type email in new browsers it will validate to a certain level. It will only look for characters followed by a @ and than a few characters after it.

Validating is to catch user mistakes not to make it harder for users to fill in your form.

Answer (score 0):

I want to replace apostrophes "'" with "/" from string.

for example: var str ="te'xt";
want output like this "te/xt"